# How to interpret a GDB backtrace?

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault

```
0x004069f1 in Space::setPosition (this=0x77733cee, x=-65, y=-49) at space.h:44    
0x00402679 in Checkers::make_move (this=0x28cbb8, move=...) at checkers.cc:351
0x00403fd2 in main_savitch_14::game::make_computer_move (this=0x28cbb8) at game.cc:153
0x00403b70 in main_savitch_14::game::play (this=0x28cbb8) at game.cc:33
0x004015fb in _fu0___ZSt4cout () at checkers.cc:96
0x004042a7 in main () at main.cc:34
```

Hello, I am coding a game for a class and I am running into a segfault. The checker pieces are held in a two dimensional array, so the offending bit appears to be invalid x/y for the array. The moves are passed as strings, which are converted to integers, thus for the x and y were somehow ASCII NULL. I noticed that in the function call make_move it says move=...

Why does it say move=...? Also, any other quick tips of solving a segfault? I am kind of new to GDB.

Comment: For starters, you should be using something like `std::vector` that would throw an easily visible exception (and otherwise save you from managing the memory) when going out of bounds (if you use `at()`). Secondly, you should be able to set up a variable watch on x and y to see how they change, and look for when they become invalid, if that truly is the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, the backtrace is trace of the calls that lead to the crash. In this case:

`game::play` called `game::make_computer_move` which called `Checkers::make_move` which called `Space::setPosition` which crashed in line 44 in file `space.h`.

Taking a look at this backtrace, it looks like you passed `-65` and `-49` to `Space::setPosition`, which if they happen to be invalid coordinates (sure look suspicious to me being negative and all). Then you should look in the calling functions to see why they have the values that they do and correct them.

I would suggest using `assert` liberally in the code to enforce contracts, pretty much any time you can say "this parameter or variable should only have values which meet certain criteria", then you should assert that it is the case.

A common example is if I have a function which takes a pointer (or more likely smart pointer) which is not allowed to be `NULL`. I'll have the first line of the function `assert(p);`. If a `NULL` pointer is ever passed, I know right away and can investigate.

Finally, run the application in gdb, when it crashes. Type `up` to inspect the calling stack  frame and see what the variables looked like: (you can usually write things like `print x` in the console). likewise, `down` will move down the call stack if you need to as well.

As for `SEGFAULT`, I would recommend runnning the application in [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). If you compile with debugging information `-g`, then it often can tell you the line of code that is causing the error (and can even catch errors that for unfortunate reasons don't crash right away).

Comment: The only problem now is discovering when they become (-65, -49). That's what a variable watch is good for.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the problem. I have no clue where or how they become -65, -49, but I guess all I can do is keep looking.

Answer (score 4):

I am not allowed to comment, but just wanted to reply for anyone looking more recently on the issue trying to find where the variables become (-65, -49). If you are getting a segfault you can get a core dump. [Here](https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/04/28/debugging-a-segfault-on-linux/) is a pretty good source for making sure you can set up gdb to get a core dump. Then you can open your core file with gdb:

```
gdb -c myCoreFile
```

Then set a breakpoint on your function call you'd like to step into:

```
b MyClass::myFunctionCall
```

Then step through with next or step to maneuver through lines of code:

```
step
```

or

```
next
```

When you are at a place in your code that you'd like to evaluate a variable you can print it:

```
p myVariable
```

or you can print all arguments:

```
info args
```

I hope this helps someone else looking to debug!